# Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

As the title suggests, I have a little problem with the relationship between my tables.

```
Unknown column 'table1.entity_id' in 'where clause'

select * from `table2` where `table1`.`entity_id` = `table2`.`id`
```

Here is the structure of my tables:

**table1**

```
id varchar(36)
type enum()
entity_id varchar(36)
```

**table2**

```
id varchar(36)
description
```

**table3**

```
id varchar(36)
brand
```

In the `table1.entity_id` column we can find the id of `table2` and `table3`.

And these are the relationships:

`Table 1`

```php
public function table2()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Model/Table2', 'entity_id');
}

public function table3()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Model/Table3', 'entity_id');
}
```

`Table 2`

```php
public function table1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Model/Table1', 'id', 'entity_id');
}
```

`Table 3`

```php
public function table1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Model/Table1', 'id', 'entity_id');
}
```

And when I do that :

```php
$query->orWhereHas('table2', function($query) use ($value) {
    $query->whereNotNull('description');
});
```

I have this error :

```
Unknown column 'table1.entity_id' in 'where clause'

select * from `table2` where `table1`.`entity_id` = `table2`.`id`
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: I think you need to make a polymorphic relationship, read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: It's not a valid join, you're not selecting any fields from 'table1'. First follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you shouldn't need to write that sql, that's why you have eloquent.